# Resetting column headings after concat

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I concatenated a `df(6000,13)` with a `sampleDf(6000,1)` and found that my col index in my pandas df as expected ranges from 0 - 12 for the df, and then displays 0 for the concatenated sampleDf.

```
  df = pd.concat([df, sampleDF], axis=1)
```

I am trying to reset this and have tried the following but nothing seems to have any effect. Any other methods I can try or any thoughts on why this may be happening?

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.reindex()
df.index = range(len(df.index))
df.index = pd.RangeIndex(len(df.index))
```

I have also tried to append `.reset_index(drop=True)` to my original concat. 
The only thing I can think of is that my data frame is 1d in length after processing and should be a pandas series perhaps?

**Edit**

I found a workaround if I transpose and then transpose again. There has to be a better way than this.

```
df = pd.concat([df, sampleDF], axis=1)
df = df.transpose()
df.index = range(len(df.index))
df = df.transpose()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply rename your columns directly:

```
df = pd.concat([df, sampleDF], axis=1)
df.columns = range(len(df.columns))
```

This will be more efficient than repeatedly transposing `df`.